# Open a form from another access database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a simple login form in access and it should take the user to their designated access database/form based on the user's login information, below is my code:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
Dim strpassword As String
Dim password As String
Dim userlevel As String

password = Me.Text0.Column(1)
userlevel = Me.Text0.Column(2)
strpassword = Me.Text4


If strpassword = password Then
If userlevel = "Admin" Then
GetObject ("C:\Users\accessdatabase.accdb")
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form"
Else
 (open other forms)
End If

Else
MsgBox "Nope"
End If

End Sub
```

I know I am doing something wrong. I actually have no idea what to do after the userlevel check. I have searched some commands online but it didn't work. Anyhelp would be really appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would declare the object as a variable:

```
Dim objAdb As Object

Set objAdb = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAdb.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\accessdatabase.accdb")
objAdb.DoCmd.OpenForm "Form"
```

regardless of your method, you need to point the docmd that you have to the other DB

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the quick reply. I applied your code and there was no error message but the form did not pop up :(  I probably missed something else?

Comment: I replicated this code using one of my own DB's and was able to open the form. Are you sure the form name is completely correct? when you step through the code does the DB open properly?

Comment: Yes, do I need to replace the "Access.application" in Set objAdb = CreateObject("Access.Application") to anything applicable please.

Comment: Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim objAdb As Object

Set objAdb = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAdb.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\Documents\Database4.accdb")
objAdb.DoCmd.OpenForm "Driver"
End Sub

Comment: the code seems to be functional for me. can you try locally running 

`docmd.openform "Driver"` in the database4 to try and drill down the issue

Comment: Hi Scott. I found out why. I added appAccess.Visible = True and appAccess.UserControl = True, now it works find. Thanks Scott. It has been a great help